# How to use HttpWebRequest.Accept?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

This is the code i used for deleting an entity,

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
request.Method = "DELETE";
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GotResponse), request);
}

private void GotResponse(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    string data;
    HttpWebRequest myrequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myrequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
        {
            System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            responseStream.Close();
        }
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(data);
        });
}
```

While using the above one, the app crashed while executing the line

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myrequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
```

sending crash message as, if proper exception handling is done it would be safe to run.
But when i removed the line

```
request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
```

Everything worked fine.

Can anyone explain me why it happened so?

Additional Info :
My server response on successful deletion is,

```
{
 "code":0,
 "message":"Successfully Deleted"
}
```

Comment: "asking to add exception" what _is_ the exception you get when calling `EndGetResponse()`? PS see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541525.aspx: "A data service MAY support this content type."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verbose `JSON` is considered a legacy format just try changing the :

```
request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
```

to

```
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
```